# How to parse the json in jquery using parseJson

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to parse this Json in Jquery

```
 {
    Result: [
    {
    name: "Ram",
    mark: "63",
    subject: "maths"
    },
    {
    name: "kumar",
    mark: "56",
    subject: "maths"
    }]
    }
```

I have tried so far using parseJson and each method in jquery.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var obj= $.parseJSON(data);
                   var arr= obj.Result;
                    $.each(arr,function(key,val){

                        console.log(val);
});
```

It throws me error like `unexpected token in o`

I need a output to get the value of the marks and the name in array.

Comment: That's not JSON. It's a JS object.

Comment: OT, doesn't test and downvoted us ? , Im not sure why I got that?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use plain old JavaScript to get out the information you need:

```
for (var i = 0, l = data.Result.length; i < l; i++) {
  var obj = data.Result[i];
  console.log(obj.name, obj.mark);
}
```

Or the slightly shorter version (>IE9):

```
data.Result.forEach(function (obj) {
  console.log(obj.name, obj.mark);
});
```

**Output**

```
"Ram" "63"
"kumar" "56"
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xgY2X/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse it, do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){



 var obj ={
    Result: [
    {
    name: "Ram",
    mark: "63",
    subject: "maths"
    },
    {
    name: "kumar",
    mark: "56",
    subject: "maths"
    }]
    };


    $.each(obj.Result,function(key,val){


    console.log(val);

        });

    });
```

Below is a demo fiddle as well:

```
$.each(data.Result,function(key,val){

console.log(val);

});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yjcdq/1/)

Answer (score 0):

**This just an object :**

```
var data = {
    Result: [{
        name: "Ram",
        mark: "63",
        subject: "maths"
    }, {
        name: "kumar",
        mark: "56",
        subject: "maths"
    }]
};

var result = data.Result;
$.each(result,function(key,val){
  console.log(val.mark);
  console.log(val.name);
});
```

**Demo :** http://jsbin.com/zofohoya/1/edit?js,console